# Scons 2.3.5 for python 3

Tags: python, scons

C:\Python34\Scripts>scons --version
scons: *** SCons version 2.3.5 does not run under Python version 3.4.3.
Python 3 is not yet supported
Anyway in which we can make python 3.4 run scons 2.3.5

Comment: You can contribute patches toward a python 3 port. But for now the answer is no you cannot make it run under python 3.x.  Any reason you cannot install python 2.7 (for now)?

Comment: i can but in mine team everyone is using python3.4

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the FAQ on the scons website:  http://www.scons.org/

https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#markdown-header-what-version-of-python-do-i-need

Sorry, but it looks like you can't use python 3 to run scons.

Comment: update, scons 2.4.0 says, "This will be the last release to support Python versions earlier than 2.7, as we begin to move toward supporting Python 3."